# How do I request for contact sensor data from ecobee API?

Tags: ecobee-api

I am trying to write a python program to download ecobee t-stat data (instead of downloading from the portal>> home IQ>> system monitor>> download data. This is because I have a number of ecobees and I want to automate it). I want to pull all the data that usually comes out as the csv file when downloading from the portal. (see below the data columns when downloading from the portal). My current code is able to pull the yellow columns from runtime report. How do I request for the data that are in red?

[data columns when downloading from the portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfMEm.png)

To get the runtime report data, I am sending an API request (I am following the guide on ecobee developer site) and receiving the following runtime report data: hvacMode,zoneHvacMode,zoneCalendarEvent,zoneCoolTemp,zoneHeatTemp,zoneAveTemp,zoneHumidity,outdoorTemp,wind,compCool1,compHeat1,fan,dmOffset.

To clarify, I want to know how to request for contact sensor data (1 or 0) that are connected to an Ecobee via API. i.e., similar to requesting for zone temperature, humidity etc. from runtime report, what report gives connected contact sensor data? Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.